# trying to push file into bitbucket repo, but showing wrong repo

Tags: repository

Normally I open a bash prompt inside my Test folder. I then git add, commit, and push origin the file and it goes into my Test folder in bitbucket. Now somehow my Test folder instead of showing .../Test (Development), it shows another repo, .../Test (Review). I do not know why it changed. How can I get (Review) to be (Development)?

Comment: Can you add the output of the commands `git remote -v` and `git branch` to your question?

Comment: git remove -v: [1]origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/our_domain/app_dir_name.git (fetch)
[2]origin  ssh://git@bitbucket.org/our_domain/app_dir_name.git (push).

git branch: shows "Development, Review, and UAT". And it shows Review highlighted. So, I presume I need to get Development highlighted/how do to that? i just tried a "git checkout Development" and it aborted.

Comment: Stackexchange allows you to edit your questions and use some markup. I edited it in for you, but it has to be reviewed first. Please use this feature next time. What does it output on your terminal when it 'aborts' the checkout? Try editing this in!

Comment: Thank you, AK! so frustrated with git and have a full plate. i'll be more informative. [a]will try looking for edit feature, never saw one, only the Add Comment. [b]when i do "git checkout Development", getting: "error: your local changes to these would be overwritten by checkout:" - then shows like 60 files, then... "Please commit changes or stash them before you switch brances...The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten..." then shows like another 50 or so files, one cuts off in mid sentence; then, "Aborting", and goes back to cursor. Sensible way through this?

Answer (score 1):

In git there are pretty much three stages. When pressing git status you probably get a similar few to this with many more files:

```
# On branch review
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   file.txt
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   file2.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   file3.txt
```

**file.txt** on top has staged changes. These will go into the next commit when you do `git commit`.

**file2.txt** has unstaged changes. This file is tracked in the repository but the changes will not be added to the next commit. Only if you `git add` this file will it get staged.

**file3.txt** is an untracked file. You have to add it with `git add` which will automatically put it into the staged area. Next time you will make changes to it you will find it in the unstaged area like file2.txt

from this situation `git checkout master` gives:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file2.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

This is probably what you get too. Git noticed that you made changes in the tracked file file2.txt but you didn't specify what to do with them. Similarly I suspect that you made changed to those '50 or so files' and now git doesn't know what to do.

Either add them to your commit and do a commit:

```
git add <files>
git commit -m "did some work"
```

or drop the changes:

```
git checkout <files>
```

Then they will return to the way they were at the last commit.

You can also add some files and drop others, or even do partial adds with `git add -p`.

Check the changes you made with `git diff`.

---

After this is resolved you can switch branches again with `git checkout <branchname>`.

Without more information on your branch structure in your bitbucket and your commit history it is hard to say what you can push to where.